# One To Many Relationship, only loads first record

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I'm having trouble with a one to many relationship. I have a user, user_company (relates a user to a company, a user can have several companies) and a user role (a user can have different roles in different companies). The problem is that the user role it's only loaded with the first user. If I test any other user the user role is null. It's really weird, I have 10 users and only the first one works. Here is the code:

User:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 14)
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 14)
@Column(name = "user_password")
private String userPassword;
@Size(max = 1)
@Column(name = "user_logged")
private String userLogged;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userCompanyUserName")
private Collection<UserCompany> userCompanyCollection;
```

User Company:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "user_company_id")
private Integer userCompanyId;
@JoinColumn(name = "user_company_user_name", referencedColumnName = "user_name")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Users userCompanyUserName;
@JoinColumn(name = "user_company_company", referencedColumnName = "company_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Companies userCompanyCompany;
/*
 @JoinColumns({
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_company_user_roles", referencedColumnName = "user_role_id"),
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_company_id", referencedColumnName = "user_role_company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 })*/
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_company_user_roles", referencedColumnName = "user_role_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_company_id", referencedColumnName = "user_role_company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private UserRoles userCompanyUserRoles;
```

User Roles:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userCompanyUserRoles")
private Collection<UserCompany> userCompanyCollection;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected UserRolesPK userRolesPK = new UserRolesPK();
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
@Column(name = "user_role_name")
private String userRoleName;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 200)
@Column(name = "user_role_description")
private String userRoleDescription;
```

About the data: 
I have 10 users, called: test1,test2,test3....
I have 10 records of user_company. They relate all the users to company1 and userrole1. 
The data is basically the same for the 10, that's why I think is really weird that only test1 works.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: This is not a JSF problem, looks like a  problem in your JPA mapping. If it is a real JSF problem, then please remove all the unnecessary code and add only the JSF code and the managed beans.

Comment: why are u joining by name :S ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging a check the SQL generated.  If it is correct, execute it directly on your database, see if you get the result you expect.

Do you create the data in your test, or is it existing?  It could be you are corrupting your cache when creating the data.  Ensure you correctly maintain your bi-directional relationships.

Comment: I have enabled SQL Logging, for both records I have exactly the same logs. The queries look good. 
The data exists. The database already has the data when the app starts running.